# All values set to null when adding Entity in a many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am creating an events app. An event can have many organizers and an organizer can have many events. I want the user to have the ability to add organizers to an existing event. This is the way the Entities are setup.

This is the `AppUser` entity (referred to as the organizer above):

```cs
public class AppUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime LastActive { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;       
    public string Location { get; set; } 
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public UserPhoto Photo { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; } 
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<UserLike> LikedByUsers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserLike> LikedUsers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> CreatedEvents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserEvents> OrganisedEvents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EventUsers> AttendingEvents { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `Event` entity:

```cs
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AppUser Creator { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserEvents> Organisers { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `UserEvents` joining entity I have created:

```cs
public class UserEvents
{
    public AppUser Organiser { get; set; }
    public int OrganiserId { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I have configured the relationships:

```cs
builder.Entity<UserEvents>()
    .HasKey(key => new {key.OrganiserId, key.EventId});
    
    builder.Entity<UserEvents>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Organiser)
        .WithMany(e => e.OrganisedEvents)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.OrganiserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<UserEvents>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Event)
        .WithMany(e => e.Organisers)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.EventId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

This is the end point I have created in my API:

```cs
[HttpPut("add-organiser/{eventId}/{organiserId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> addOrganiser(int eventId, int organiserId)    
{
    var existingEvent = await _eventsRepository.GetEventByIdAsync(eventId);
    var organiser = await _userRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(organiserId);

    var userEvent = new UserEvents {
        OrganiserId = organiserId,
        Organiser = organiser,
        EventId = eventId,
        Event = existingEvent
    };

    // ALL THE VALUES ABOVE ARE CORRECTLY ASSIGNED

    existingEvent.Organisers = existingEvent.Organisers ?? new List<UserEvents>();
    existingEvent.Organisers.Add(userEvent);

    if(await _eventsRepository.SaveAllAsync())
        return Ok();

    return BadRequest("Failed to add organiser");
}
```

The event id and organizer id are correctly being added to the `UserEvents` join table, the problem I am having is that the organizers properties are appearing as null in the `Event` entity. See image of the organizers array taken from Postman:

[image]

This is the code where I am querying the `Event` entity:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EventDto>>> GetAllEvents()
        {
            var events = await _eventsRepository.GetEventsAsync();

            return Ok(events);
        }
```

Here is the `GetEventsAsync()` method from the `_eventsRepository`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EventDto>> GetEventsAsync()
  {
     return await _context.Events
      .Include(e => e.Creator)
      .Include(e => e.Photos)
      .Include(e => e.Organisers)
      .ThenInclude(e => e.Organiser)
      .ProjectTo<EventDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
      .ToListAsync();
  }
```

This is the `EventDto` I am mapping to:

```
public class EventDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }   
        public string MainPhotoUrl { get; set; }    
        public ICollection<PhotoDto> Photos { get; set; }    
        public MemberDto Creator { get; set; }    
        public ICollection<MemberDto> Organisers { get; set; }    
        public ICollection<MemberDto> Attendees { get; set; }           
    }
}
```

The Organisers here are mapped from the `AppUser` to the `MemberDto`:

```
public class MemberDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime LastActive { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;      
        public string Location { get; set; } 
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }     
        public string Occupation { get; set; }
        public PhotoDto Photo { get; set; }

    }
```

Finally, here is the relevant code from my Automapper configuration:

```
public AutoMapperProfile() {
            CreateMap<AppUser, MemberDto>();
            CreateMap<Event, EventDto>();
}
```

Comment: You must use `Include` to get `existingEvent` with its `Organisers`. But there's mismatch between this `Organisers` collection and "organisers" in the Json. It's not clear how they relate.

Comment: Hi Gert, thank you for your response. I have added the 'Include' but still the same issues remain. As mentioned in my OP, I omitted several of the AppUser properties as I felt they were relevant to the question but I will amend my OP to include all the properties

Comment: "_the problem I am having is that the organizers properties are appearing as null in the Event entity_" -  then you are supposed to share the code how you are querying the the `Event` entity.

Comment: Apologies, I will update the OP with the code for when I am querying the entity

Comment: Also, thanks for the edits. Organizers is the spelling used in the US, whereas Organisers is more commonly used in the UK.